# f:validateLongRange. Validation huge numbers

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, validatelongrange

I am using JSF 2 and primefaces 3.5. I have an inputText which must be a number between Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE.

```
<p:inputText id="startRange" value="#{attributeBean.attribute.startRange}">
<f:convertNumber />
<f:validateLongRange minimum="#{attributeBean.minimumValue}" 
                     maximum="#{attributeBean.maximumValue}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

In attributeBean:

```
public Long getMinimumValue(){
  return Long.MIN_VALUE;
}
public Long getMaximumValue(){
  return Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

When I enter a huge number like 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 validation message doesn't appear. If come back to this form in an inputText field is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 value. Can I get a validation message?

Comment: Do you have a `h:message`-tag anywhere?

Comment: of course. I use it like this: <p:message for="startRange"/>

Answer (score 0):

Well this is do to the f:converter. The converter tries to convert `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
To a long. The max of a long =  9,223,372,036,854,775,807 so the converter works well :-)

But this behavior is not what you want i guess. So you can validate it yourself on this way. Add a actionListener to your command button: `actionListener="#{attributeBean.validateLong}"` and remove this:

```
<f:validateLongRange minimum="#{attributeBean.minimumValue}" 
                     maximum="#{attributeBean.maximumValue}"/>
```

and add a method like this in your bean:

```
public void validateLong() 
{ 
 if(startRange.compareTo(Long.MIN_VALUE) > 0 && startRange.compareTo(Long.MAX_VALUE) < 0)
 {
    //Do bussiness logic
 }
 else
 {
     //Throw message
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Not good!"));
 }        
}
```

Keep in mind that your range with above check is between: -9223372036854775807 and 9223372036854775806. But i don't know if thats a problem.

Comment: I don't understand how a long variable startRange will keep a value bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE (startRange.compareTo(Long.MAX_VALUE) ???). And I try to use a listener, but it has worked only if a value smaller than Long.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: My solution checks if the long isn't bigger the Max - 1 do that you get your validation message.  And your original input stays preserved

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved with help `<f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Long"/>`